# Error:Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: android, android-billing

I got the error while compiling my Android Code. Can anyone help me with the code. Following is the logo - (for privacy i removed the path and name it as path)

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugAidl'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        Path/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aidl -p/Path/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/framework.aidl -o/Path/android/build/generated/source/aidl/debug -I/Path/android/src -I/Path/android/src/debug/aidl -

I/Path/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/BFP/BaseGameUtils/1.0/aidl -
I/Path/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/20.0.0/aidl -d/tmp/aidl7429266825249614170.d 

path/Android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService
      Error Code:
        1
      Output:
        Some path/Android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl:45 interface IInAppBillingService should be declared in a file called com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was mistake on my part!

While changing the package name not every file get update, Don't know why?

Now I checked all the file and manually changed the package where it was wrong now it's working well.

So, When Ever this kind of error come I would suggest you to check the package name in the files.

> Note: If you use the starting package with other than .com like .in,
>   make sure billing package should be in .com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `IInAppBillingService.aidl` is in the correct location.

The folder hierarchy should be like this.
[image]

Comment: You should not change the package name of `IInAppBillingService.aidl`. Change it back and your code will work.

Comment: I mean to say I changed the package no of my app not the billing one

Comment: Thanks I accidentally copied the file into the `vending` folder rather than `billing`